# Joda Time not getting right Islamic Date

Tags: android, date, jodatime

i need to get 3 islamic dates and i'm using Joda Time to convert dates.

date1:

```
DateTime todayIso = new DateTime(2014, 4, 20,0,0,0);
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tehran");
    DateTime dtIslamic = 
            todayIso.withChronology(
                    IslamicChronology.getInstance(
                            tz, 
                            IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED));
    Log.d("DATE !", dtIslamic.getYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getMonthOfYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getDayOfMonth());
```

result is "1435 6 19" It's Wrong and should be "1435 6 20".

date2:

```
DateTime todayIso = new DateTime(2015, 2, 15,0,0,0);
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tehran");
    DateTime dtIslamic = 
            todayIso.withChronology(
                    IslamicChronology.getInstance(
                            tz, 
                            IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED));
    Log.d("DATE !", dtIslamic.getYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getMonthOfYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getDayOfMonth());
```

result is "1436 1 25" It's True.

date 3:

```
DateTime todayIso = new DateTime(2015, 12, 2,0,0,0);
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tehran");
    DateTime dtIslamic = 
            todayIso.withChronology(
                    IslamicChronology.getInstance(
                            tz, 
                            IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED));
    Log.d("DATE !", dtIslamic.getYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getMonthOfYear()+" "+ dtIslamic.getDayOfMonth());
```

result is "1437 2 19" It's Wrong and should be "1437 2 20".

the first month of islamic date in year 1437 have 29 days but it's show day 30 too.